# Вместо 'Привет Мир!' выводит ??????

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Вместо 'Привет Мир!' выводит � � � � � � � � � � � ! Подскажите...

```
$str = 'Привет Мир!';
for($i=0; $i<strlen($str); $i++) {
    echo $str[$i], ' ';
}
```

А вот так выводит нормально:

```
$str = 'Привет Мир!';
echo $str;
```

Answer (score 4):

Воспользуйтесь функцией `mb_substr`:

```
$str = 'Привет Мир!'; 
for($i=0; $i<strlen($str); $i++) 
{ 
    echo mb_substr($str, $i, 1, 'utf-8'), ' '; 
}
```

Более детально:

1. [Wrong output when using array indexing on UTF-8 string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6315770)
2. [mb_substr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php)

Comment: Спасибо Вам, Павел Азанов! Все получилось!

Comment: Я вставляю свой код в фигурные скобки, а он у меня здесь на форуме почему-то не отображается отформатированным. Почему? Что нужно сделать?

Comment: $str = 'Привет Мир!'; echo $str;

Comment: @anton: Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его, а затем нажмите кнопку {} в редакторе. Если ответ Вас устраивает, то Вы можете принять его нажав на галочку под счетчиком голосов за/против ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Помимо всех махинаций, вам ещё нужно отправить заголовки :

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Если код написан в пустом файле.

Если это **UTF-8**, то **strlen** для кирилицы выведет длину в 22 символа(может 20) ибо символы там закодированы в 2 байта, потому нам нужна функция **mb_strlen**. Пробуйте.

Answer (score 0):

Кодировку файла выставь utf-8 и в корне своего проекта или сайта создай файл .htaccess и вставь в него строчку AddDefaultCharset utf8

Comment: У меня все так и сделано. Здесь повидимому подвох в том, что строка выводится как массив...

Comment: mountpoint скопируйте код, протестируйте у себя. Если выведет ??? значит проблема не в кодировке.

Comment: Да, UTF-8 без BOM. У Вас этот код работает?

Comment: @anton, да, у меня такая же лажа... странно